# How can I colour my code?

Tags: format

A student in another class coloured their code in their word document, I asked my teacher if he knew how and he suggested he coloured it all by hand... I'm very sure he didn't colour hundreds of lines of code by hand.

I've also seen many websites that colour the code snippets to help with readability - including StackOverflow!

Here's a print screen of the code contained in the word document.

[image: img]

as you can see they're not print-screens as not only can I highlight the text, word has underlined what it thinks are errors in spelling / grammar.

Comment: pretty sure copy and paste from Visual Studio will do this (other IDEs may do the same)

Comment: There's a limit it reaches and then doesn't do a rich text copy. (using Visual Studio 2019. Setting: Text Editor, Advanced, Copy rich text on copy cut, Max length).

Answer (score 0):

When you copy-paste into a Word document, it (by default) retains the formatting of the text copied into it. IDEs (e.g., Visual Studio, Eclipse, IntelliJ, etc.) usually perform syntax highlighting (i.e., color different elements of the code differently in order to highlight their purpose) for you. If you copy and paste from the IDE you've used to create the code, it will probably retain this formatting.